# How do I set up GTM tracking for clicks on a casino game?

Tags: google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I need to be able to track clicks on a casino game on a site. I've tried a bunch of methods that I believe should be working, but are not. Such as trying to track certain classes, CSS-selectors and links. The casino games have links to an internal site, which then redirects to an external site.

It doesn't seem like the debugger is able to track my clicks on the games. However when clicking anywhere else on the site, I see "click" show up in the debugger.